# OAuthSwift - "No Such Module OAuthSwift"

Tags: api, swift, github, frameworks, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to use the OAuthSwift Framework in my swift app and I get the error "No such module 'OAuthSwift' " when I `import swift`.

I followed the following instructions from the github read:

```
Drag OAuthSwift.xcodeproj to your project in the Project Navigator.
Select your project and then your app target. Open the Build Phases panel.
Expand the Target Dependencies group, and add OAuthSwift framework.
import OAuthSwift whenever you want to use OAuthSwift.
```

I have OAuthSwift.xcodeproj in my Supporting Files

In Target Dependencies I have `OAuthSwift (OAuthSwift)`. Link Binary with libraries and Copy bundle resources are both blank.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any luck with this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Same here. Any update @Marcus?

Comment: You have to use pod to import Libraries.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm using OAuthSwift version 1.0.0 and having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to import OAuthSwift at places you are planning to use OAuth.

Before doing so, you need to add OAuthSwift into Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

However, I would prefer using cocoa pods to add dependencies to you project.

Here is a link "how to install Cocoapods"
[2](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7mOmuwOrMAhXjL6YKHajJDH0QFggkMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F20755044%2Fhow-to-install-cocoa-pods&usg=AFQjCNFRnNDoohMJFMwpVHoCpPeoh5qrLg&sig2=Rz3eiDNdSsCsuCbUkMgNvg): Here is how you install CocoaPods

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue

what I did was:

Look into the App Target -> General: Embed binaries (right click, open in finder)

Drag the the `OAuthSwift.Framework` into my project under "app-name-folder", a portfolio icon should show next to "OAuthSwift.framework", then import it again into the Embedded Binaries and remove the OAuthSwift.xcodeproj (not necessary anymore)

let me know how it all went